# Regex: select the whole link if it contains example.com/20

Tags: java, android, regex

I am using linkify in android and I want to fire my own activity for links that contains `example.com/20` and fire implicit intent for other links.

**For example clicking these links should fire my own activity.**

```
    https://example.com/2013/04/blah-blah-balh.html
    http://example.com/2005/04/jurassic-pack-ola.html
    https://www.example.com/2012/07/tlion-film-nolly.html
    http://www.example.com/2016/08/rolj-ola-ola-po-me-them.html
```

**These links should fire implicit intent**

```
    http://www.example.com/rolj-ola-ola-po-me-them.html
    https://hopeman.com/2016/12/juujjhgg.html
    https://ekapurk.com/2001/04/tyhtt-poiuut-i.html
```

I tested `\bexample(.com\/{20})?\b` in http://regexr.com/ but it's only highlighlighting **example**

Comment: So, try `String pattern = "\\bexample[.]com/20"`, `\/{20}` matches 20 slashes, but `(.com\/{20})?` is optional, does not have to be matched, as `?` means *1 or 0 occurrences*. And the `.` can match any char but a newline.

Comment: You are properly more interested in using `https?:\/\/(www\.)?example\.com\/20`.

Comment: @rekire, I am also interesed in http

Comment: @Ozuf the questionmark says the char or group before is optional ;-) in other words it will match http and https.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
String pattern = "\\bexample[.]com/20";
```

Or if you need to match the full string:

```
String pattern = "https?://(?:w{3}[.])?example[.]com/20\\S*";
```

Note that `\/{20}` matches 20 slashes, and `(.com\/{20})?` is optional, does not have to be matched, as `?` means *1 or 0 occurrences*. Also, the `.` can match any char but a newline, and it should be either escaped or put inside a character class.

See [this regex demo 1](https://regex101.com/r/kO4fB2/1) and [regex demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/lF5kN3/1).

Pattern details:

- `https?` - match `http` or `https` (as `s?` means match 1 or 0 `s`s)
- `://` - literal sequence `://`
- `(?:w{3}[.])?` - 1 or 0 (=optional) 3 letters `w` and a literal dot after them (`www.`)
- `example[.]com/20` - a literal string `example.com/20`
- `\S*` - zero or more (`*`) characters other than whitespace.

Comment: I have never seen `[.]` to mask an dot. However it seems to work :-) Just my personal opinion but `w{3}[.]` is less readable then `www\.` and it is also two letters shorter.

Comment: @rekire: It is not actually *masking*, it is just a way to define a literal dot in the pattern. In order not to get lost among backslashes.

Comment: @Shafizadeh: It would mean using 2 backslashes in Android regex.

Comment: @Ozuf: Happy coding!

Answer (score 2):

You might want to check for `https?:\/\/(www\.)?example\.com\/20` which will match for http and https urls on example.com or www.example.com domain which starts with `/20` in the url.

In that case you just need to embed your url in the html tag and you are done.